# taking screen short from url webview in application off linemode in android

Tags: android, web-services, broadcastreceiver, android-webview

i need some guide from here.now my need is.how to take screen short from URL using web view while application is not running.is that is possible?.kindly tell the solution for this stuff i already done the code for taking screen short for while application in running.
  here is my code:

this code showing the error:

```
public class FirePaperActivity extends Activity {

Runnable webRunner = new backgroundSnapper();
Thread webSnapping;
backgroundSnapper back;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    back.webActivState = true;
    takingSnap();
}
void takingSnap() {

    final Handler snapHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            webSnapping = new Thread(webRunner);
            webSnapping.start();

        }
    };
    snapHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}
public class backgroundSnapper implements Runnable {
    WebView webview;
    boolean webActivState;

    public backgroundSnapper() {
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            while (webActivState) {
                Picture picture = webview.capturePicture();
                Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(picture.getWidth(),
                        picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
                picture.draw(c);
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/yahoo_"
                            + System.currentTimeMillis() + "rma.jpg");
                    if (fos != null) {
                        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
                        fos.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // ...
                }

            }

            Thread.sleep(60000);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

}

}
```

this is the log cat error

```
11-03 10:06:35.800: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2428): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 10:06:35.800: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2428): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thinkpal.live/com.thinkpal.live.FirePaperActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-03 10:06:35.800: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
11-03 10:06:35.800: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
11-03 10:06:35.800: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-03 10:06:35.800: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2428):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
11-03 10:06:35.800: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2428):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-03 10:06:35.800: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2428):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-03 10:06:35.800: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-03 10:06:35.800: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2428):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 10:06:35.800: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2428):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-03 10:06:35.800: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2428):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
11-03 10:06:35.800: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2428):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
11-03 10:06:35.800: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2428):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-03 10:06:35.800: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2428): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-03 10:06:35.800: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2428):     at com.thinkpal.live.FirePaperActivity.onCreate(FirePaperActivity.java:30)
11-03 10:06:35.800: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2428):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-03 10:06:35.800: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
w = new WebView(this); 
    w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
    { 
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
            { 
                    Picture picture = view.capturePicture(); 
            Bitmap  b = Bitmap.createBitmap( picture.getWidth(), 
picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
            Canvas c = new Canvas( b ); 
            picture.draw( c ); 
            FileOutputStream fos = null; 
            try { 
                    fos = new FileOutputStream( "/sdcard/yahoo_" + 
System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg" ); 
                    if ( fos != null ) 
                    { 
                            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos ); 
                            fos.close(); 
                    } 
            } catch( Exception e ) 
                    { 
                    //... 
                    } 
            } 
      });
```

Try this code its works fine.If you have any doubt refer this page
[Reference Page](https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5bab2668cd5ab44f/efd2e7cfd14e4b16?lnk=gst&q=yahoo#efd2e7cfd14e4b16)

use this code to periodically take snapshot for every one minutes, and you need to initialize the boolean variable webActiveState as true while launching activity contain webview and reinitialize as false  while stop or destroy() the activity

```
    //Taking Snap
     void takingSnap(){

    Runnable webRunner= new  backgroundSnapper();
    Thread webSnapping;
final Handler snapHandler = new Handler(){
                public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {


                    webSnapping =new Thread(webRunner);

                    webSnapping.start();

                    }
                };
              snapHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}

 public class backgroundSnapper implements Runnable {

  public backgroundSnapper(){
  }

  public void run() {


            try{
             while(webActivState)
             {
            Picture picture = webview.capturePicture(); 
            Bitmap  b = Bitmap.createBitmap( picture.getWidth(), 
            picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
            Canvas c = new Canvas( b ); 
            picture.draw( c ); 
            FileOutputStream fos = null; 
            try { 
                    fos = new FileOutputStream( "/sdcard/yahoo_" + 
        System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg" ); 
                    if ( fos != null ) 
                    { 
                            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos ); 
                            fos.close(); 
                    } 
            } catch( Exception e ) 
                    { 
                    //... 
                    } 

             }

        Thread.sleep(60000);

         }
        catch(Exception e){

          }
    }

   }
```

To reset web Active state

```
protected void onStop() {
            System.gc();
           back.webActiveState=false;

            super.onStop();

        };  
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            back.webActiveState=false;
       super.onDestroy();
```

Comment: thank you for your reply i have alrady done this and i save this image on sd card also.my need is.in this application should run in background.its take screen short on every 1 minute.if it is possible?.kindly guide me.what code i need to add in application running on background?.

Comment: now i edit my code is show foreclose.and also post my logcat error.where i have to false that webActiveState?

Comment: :now also showing same error.i think i need to put load url.where i have to put that code and how?